# Failed-loading xdebug installation - xdebug.so, 9 no suitable image found

Tags: php, xdebug, failed-installation

After installing xdebug extentions as follows

- Download xdebug-2.6.0alpha1.tgz
- Unpack the downloaded file
- Run: cd xdebug-2.6.0alpha1
- Run: phpize
- Run: ./configure
- Run: make
- Run: cp modules/xdebug.so
  /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.26_18/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012
- Edit /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini and add the line zend_extension =
  /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.26_18/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so

I get the error when run php -v

```
Failed loading /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.26_18/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so:  
dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.26_18/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  
Did find:
/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.26_18/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so: 
stat() failed with errno=20
```

When I use the service of Xdebug analyse popinfo() output, it will ask the exactly the same steps to do.

It am not sure what no suitable image found means. The path exists. Could anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of PHP installed?

Comment: Yes, most likely, before installing xdebug but after installed php70 through brew (version 7.0.26_18), when I check `php -v`, the output was `PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: jul 15 2017)`. 
I set my mac to factory setting last week, so it should clean unless the php came along with other downloads.

Comment: The `20151012` part in the path is Zend API version (you can check that from the header of `phpinfo()` or `php -i` output). This one is for PHP 7.0 .. while you must be trying to load it for PHP 7.1 somehow...

Comment: I don't need PHP7.1, do you know how to get rid of it? or How I can use 7.0.26 version instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted the problem out by adding

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH"
```

on .bash_profile.

PHP 7.1 came with OSX 10.13.2, so default path was set to the pre-packed php, which shows the error on phpinfo.