# Xdebug error on local environment [Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so:]

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I want to use Xdebug on the vscode.

I tried it while reading the official documentation, but I couldn’t get it to work and got the following error.

```
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so: stat() failed with errno=20
```

php --ini

```
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so: stat() failed with errno=20
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

Has anyone else encountered the same problem?
Thank you.

Comment: - Mac Catalina 10.15.5  
- PHP 7.4  
- Laravel Laravel version 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by doing something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054252

I added

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix php)/bin:$PATH"
```

to `~/.bash_profile`.

You can run `source ~/.bash_profile` after editing the file to get the changes to take effect.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Running macOS High Sierra and php@7.2